SQL Server Always encrypted feature
Is there a way to accomplish the following? I have a client that uses 2 databases, one for their live work and one where they store their archive data.
They recently encrypted a few columns in the live database and have been running into issues with their archive process. Since there are 2 keys (one for each database), they keep running into errors:

Operand type clash: varbinary is incompatible with varchar(25) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'stuff', column_encryption_key_name = 'morestuff', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'waymorestuff') collation_name = 'Latin1_General_BIN2'

Is there a way to accomplish this? I have tried to use cursors to pull the old data from the live database and insert it into the archive.

Please run this query: SELECT @@version; and report the result.

This is not a  language related tag. Which dbms are you using?

Why have they encrypted those columns anyway, do they know how Always Encrypted works? It protects against sysadmins by encrypting on the client. The server has no knowledge of the encryption. Note the docs "The following features don't work on encrypted columns: Cross-database queries that perform joins on columns (using deterministic encryption) from different databases." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16

AlwaysEncrypted is client-side encryption.  To make this work they would need to run code on a client machine with access to the encryption keys that decrypts and then re-encrypts the data.
